# How to open SSH tunnel to share VPN connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, network-share, ssh-tunnel

There is one Windows machine which can SSH into Linux server within VPN connection. How I can setup SSH tunnel (or anything else) on this Windows machine, which could be shared for other machine under same Wi-Fi?[image]

Comment: What VPN client do you use on Windows machine?

Comment: @AbuZaid It's Cisco AnyConnect.